# Does calling Process.killProcess reclaim dynamically allocated memory from native code?

Tags: android, c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, android-ndk

I have a long running JNI process that resides in its own remote service. It's a third party library, that doesn't react to Java's cancellation, but I need the ability to cancel it.

If I kill the remote service's process, am I assured that any and all memory allocated by the native third party library is freed? Or will it leak?

Comment: Anything it allocated should be freed.  If it caused an application in some other process to allocate, and that other process doesn't notice that it died, then that memory would still be around.  But any pages allocated through malloc() or mmap() will be returned to the system.  Of course, the process actually has to die -- you can't kill one app from another app with a different UID.

Comment: Right, it's the same application that's calling Process.killProcess, so It's definitely dying.

Comment: Ok, while the thread's execution is terminated, I think it's still leaking memory. I am getting the size of the allocated memory in my native heap, and it's going up and down, but has an upward trend. Do processes share native heap in Android?